# How ignore Bootstrap class with Jest and VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I try to create a unitary test for my website and I have this error:
`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

```
       9 |
      10 |             <div>
    > 11 |                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addTableModal">Add table...</button>
         |                                               ^
      12 |                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="removeCurrent" v-if="tab.length > 0">Remove</button>
      13 |             </div>
      14 |         </div>
```

I understand that Jest does not interpret the Bootstrap classes, how I tell it to use Bootstrap or to ignore the classes, because I don't want to test them.

Comment: The problem is not Bootstrap class, the error points to wrong line because there's a problem with sourcemaps. The real problem is what the error says, `Cannot use import statement outside a module`. The problem is that Jest wasn't configured properly to work with modules and it didn't transform `import` statements. It's unknown what exactly is wrong on your side. Check against the docs, for starters https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/testing-single-file-components-with-jest.html